# How can I copy only one page on iPad pages app?

Tags: ios, ipad, pages

I want to copy only one page in my document at Pages app (iPad), but there seems no way to do it, as the copy button that is triggered by tapping on the specific page on the left-side bar seems to copy the entire page.

But I need to copy only the first and second pages of my document, and copy it to the head of another document. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Why not duplicate the doc and then delete pages not needed? The jmh answer works well for me, but it seems it’s not what you wanted?

Comment: @bmike It’s not possible. If you delete one page the other pages also disappear because they are set together.

Comment: I wonder if you could share such a document online, maybe recreate it in three pages or less with filler / public safe info?

Answer (score 1):

open the document and at the top, you see an icon that looks like a page divided into 1/3 and 2/3. See the image below. Tap on that icon and you'll see "Page Thumbnails". Turn that on and then tap on the document. You'll see the thumbnails on the left. Tap on the Thumbnails you want and you'll get an option to copy or edit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did it but doesn’t it copy all the pages on the document (from 1 to 4 in your case)? That’s what I meant in my question.

Comment: did you click one page in the left sidebar?

Comment: Yes, and I think you can only select the entire document. Were you able to copy the page to another document successfully? From your screenshot you also seem to select the entire document.

Comment: What’s wrong with just selecting everything on the page and pressing copy?

Answer (score -1):

It's now possible to select multiple pages at the same time and then copy them.

To do this, open the document from which you want to copy pages in Pages. Then, make sure you can see the page thumbnails<sup>1</sup>.

Now that you are able to see all of the pages in the document, tap and hold one page and (without releasing your finger), click on other pages you want to select. Then, press "Copy" to copy the three of them. Here, I tapped and held on the first page and selected pages 2 and 3 (so the pages 1,2 and 3 are selected).

[image]

**Note:** You can also select all of the pages if you want, the screenshot is only an example.

To paste them to another document, open the document where you want to paste them, click on a page thumbnail and select "Paste". This will paste the selected pages *below* the page you clicked on. Here, I clicked on page 1 and selected "Paste", so the three copied pages appear below page 1 - of course, you can move page 1 to the bottom to have the pasted pages at the top.

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup>*Click on the folder icon and make sure "Page Thumbnails" is enabled.*

[image]

<sup>*(Click image to open full size)*</sup>

Comment: Seriously? What's the problem here? I don't think the downvoter even ***read*** the answer. I'm starting to think I'm being targeted... Anyone to explain??